# Running Kestrel with http/2

Tags: nginx, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

I need to support http/2 on my web app running inside a container and I'm having a hard time to configure Kestrel to run http/2 with my self-signed certificates.

What I want to ask is, is there a difference running Kestrel behind Nginx and handling all http/2 communication on Nginx and supporting http/2 at Kestrel level?

To summarize there are two options:
1. Run Asp.Net Core app behind Nginx and on http. Http/2 is handled by Nginx.
2. Run Asp.Net Core with http/2 support.

Which way should I prefer?

Answer (score 1):

For any production environment, it is better to use a dedicated reverse proxy (like Nginx) instead of exposing the application directly. They are more specialized for this purpose and usually provide better security and performance. ASP.NET Core documentation also recommends using separate reverse proxy for these reasons https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1